# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest and chrome CSP

Tags: redirect, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I have an extension that redirects certain webrequests using the
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest API.

Now since Facebook implemented the CSP Header, the redirects are
fired, but the network tab in chrome just says PENDING request.

So I guess its being blocked.

How can I get around this ???

Comment: Can you please put your request and to which request you have redirected?

Comment: It may be happening because the URL to which you have redirected may not be a valid URL or does not return anything..

Comment: It is working on opera, comodo and coolnovo (all chrome based) and it was working on chrome before facebook added CSP.

But I can give the script for blocking(redirecting)

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
 function(details) {
  var url = "www.example.com?v=sd" ;
  return {redirectUrl: url};
 },
 { urls: ["*://gnocchi-www.buffalo-ggn.net/*/staticData"] },
 ["blocking"]);

Comment: Also look at the javascript console in both the tab and the extension's background page. If the tab's CSP blocks something you'll see an error message in the tab's console.